# How to build a JEE project with EAR, EJB and WEB in maven?

Tags: intellij-idea, ejb, ear

I'm using Intellij idea.
I'm used to work on Spring Applications and not on EJB.
what are the steps should I follow so it generates EAR,EJB and WEB modules from a maven project?

Comment: Note that in case of a Maven/Gradle projects IDE creates application's [artifacts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-artifacts.html) automatically based on pom.xml/build.gradle files, so you should configure everything in maven pom.xml.

Comment: You don't need to use EAR files anymore. EJBs may be declared and used directly in WAR files now.